# How to sort T-SQL query output in a custom order?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by

I am using `SQL Server 2014`. I need the output of my `T-SQL` query to be sorted in a specific order.

I have tried the following but it is not working as I intended. Here is an extract of the last part of my `T-SQL` query:

```
...  
GROUP BY xx.[Market]

ORDER BY CASE
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'France' THEN '1'
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'United Kingdom' THEN '2'
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'Germany' THEN '3'
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'Belgium' THEN '4'
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'Reunion' THEN '5'
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'South Africa' THEN '6'
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'Russia' THEN '7'
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'Middle East' THEN '8'
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'Central Europe' THEN '9'
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'Poland' THEN '10'
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'Scandinavia' THEN '11'
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'Netherlands' THEN '12'
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'India' THEN '13'
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'G&I' THEN '14'
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'China' THEN '15'
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'OTA' THEN '16'
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'Web Direct' THEN '17'
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'DB Local' THEN '18'
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'DB International' THEN '19'
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'Other Markets' THEN '20'

ELSE xx.[Market] END
```

However, I am getting the following results:

```
Market               RN
France               196
Scandinavia           80
Netherlands          320
India                  2
OTA                  372
Web Direct           140
DB Local              11
DB International      25
United Kingdom     2,424
Other Markets        116
Germany              609
Belgium              350
Reunion               27
South Africa          42
Russia                 7
Central Europe        17
Switzerland           34
```

Is it because some markets are not included in the output? If yes, how do I handle this issue (as there will be cases where markets which are missing in this output might be present when I will use my query with different filters)?

Comment: Usually by about the tenth `WHEN`, you should be wondering whether it's more sensible to be modelling this as an `DisplayOrder` column (either in an existing table or a new one just for this purpose).

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Well, if you have to actually write the tenth before that idea pops to mind, you should probably have more coffee before resuming work :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using string values in CASE clause use numeric values.

```
ORDER BY CASE
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'France' THEN 1
WHEN xx.[Market] = 'United Kingdom' THEN 2
...
ELSE 1000
END
```